# How to enter the first N results on Google search using Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

When I trying to enter the first N results, it enters only the first / the first four below the first one.

any help?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

query = 'How to enter the first results on Google'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.google.com')

search = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'q')
search.send_keys(query)
search.submit()

# RESULTS_LOCATOR = "//div/h3/a" # GIVING THE FIRST ONES ONLY

RESULTS_LOCATOR = '//div\[@class="g"\]//h3/a'

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, RESULTS_LOCATOR)))

page_results = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, RESULTS_LOCATOR)

for item in page_results:
item.click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.back()
time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the wrong XPath for what you're trying to do. Chrome makes it really easy to test XPaths, by going to the inspector and clicking `ctrl+F`/`cmd+F` in the Elements tab (image below). It looks like the `g` classname is reserved for the 1-5 featured results at the top of each results page, which would explain why you're only ever getting a few.

By inspecting the page and looking at each of the result links, I found that each link seems to contain an `h3` with `class="LC20lb MBeuO DKV0Md"`. With that information, I constructed the XPath `//h3[starts-with(@class,"LC20lb")]/..`. (Because I know I'm eventually going to want the link, I added `..` to the end to get the parent element, which is the `a` tag that contains the link.)

Also, your code will raise a `StaleElementReferenceException` when you try to go back to the search page and access the next result, since you're attempting to access a page element that no longer exists. Instead, you can extract all the links beforehand, and navigate to each of them in turn:

```
RESULTS_LOCATOR = '//h3[starts-with(@class,"LC20lb")]/..'

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, RESULTS_LOCATOR)))

page_results = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, RESULTS_LOCATOR)

links = [element.get_attribute('href') for element in page_results]

for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(2)
```

[image: chrome's inspector, opened to Elements tab, with search bar containing an XPath]